# grep also returning non matching lines

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, regular-expression

I'm trying to `grep` the output of `strings` and only find lines that start with a certain number of `=` chars. I tried `strings data.txt | grep ^=*`

Sample output:

```
1~{,
 WX2
};K,<
========== truKLdjsbJ5g7yyJ2X2R0o3a5HQJFuLk
Nqp@
w"#/6>
QE++
6?M 
V9p>
Y22f
'WT$
v?4s
xp,b
ai2v>/
```

In my terminal, the long series of `=` chars is highlighted in red, so `grep` is successfully matching it, but I'm also getting all the others. I've checked `man grep` which says that by default `grep` should only print matching lines, and indeed that's what I usually observe, but in this case that's definitely not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^=*` means search for a line starting with zero or more equal signs.

If you want lines starting with = just use `^=`

Comment: Thanks, I actually want lines that contain more than one `=` so it seem `^==*` will do the trick.

Comment: `^==*` will return any line with 1 or more `=` signs. The functionality of this would be equivalent to `^=+`  If you want more than one, you should use  `grep -E '^={2,}'` according to the grep manpage